# Not allowed to load local resourse JSP

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages

I have my index.html page in GitHub pages and my JS code in my local machine.

```
<script src="C:\\Users\\vivek\\Desktop\\scrc.js"></script>
```

This is my JS code source link.
When I tried to load the web page after publishing in GitHub pages it showed error as

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C://Users//vivek//Desktop//scrc.js
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why don't use local server like XAMPP?

Comment: I'm planning to use self generated JS files by each client to be used for my application which contains user specific keys.

Answer (score 0):

look like browser don't have permission to get access the storage disk of local machine .that's why this error is shown to solve this use server full path where the file is uploaded and also server dont have access to your project it make new project and store file in another folder with same name where server build the project and uploaded file .it's like if you are making a project and server is also making second project which have access and show image file dynamically.
and simply copy paste the file in project where you are writing and give path it will also work.